# Send WhatsApp message from C#

Tags: c#, .net, whatsapp

I was trying to send a WhatsApp message using a console application and all my searches I made on the internet for the same lead me to the NuGet **WhatsAppAPI**. I understand that because this not being an official client WhatsApp has blocked it currently.

Do we have another way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 6):

After some googling I've found this useful link: https://blog.cloudrail.com/whatsapp-api-how-to-use-the-whatsapp-chat-api/

Basically it says:

> At the moment, there is no official WhatsApp API to use. There are
> some libraries available which use an unofficial API to send and
> receive messages, but this is only limited to a single number. All
> those libraries are basically hacks which try to act like a standard
> WhatsApp client which you see on Android or iOS in combination with
> WhatsApp Web. Nevertheless, there is one official offering by
> WhatsApp: the Click to Chat API, which is basically only a link containing a target number and a prefilled text. Once a user clicks on this link, the WhatsApp client (Android, iOS, Web, etc) opens with a new message to the prefilled number with the prefilled text. This is a cool way to add a fast contact option for example if you want to sell your car. (see this link for more about 'WhatsApp Click To Chat': https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251).
>
> If you want to play around with messaging platforms to build chatbots or other systems, have a look at Facebook Messenger, Telegram, Viber, Slack or Line.

Hope this helps

**Update 19.05.2022:** Meta just anounced a public API for businesses of any size. I will update this answer as soon as there are more infos about this.
Source: https://www.facebook.com/4/posts/10114482926371251/

Answer (score 0):

After some digging: "WhatsApp is intentionally a closed system without an API for external access."

You will have to embrace skillz/madness to pull this off, which, sadly, we will not publicly help you with.

Bon chance!